# Problemas com Assembly

Tags: assembly

Comecei recentemente estudar Arquitetura de computadores na qual é necessário saber essa linguagem.

Por se tratar de uma linguagem de montagem (linguagem de baixo nível), não encontrei nenhuma IDE para eu poder testar os programas e executar os exercícios.

Existe a possibilidade de criar um programa 100% Assembly no DevC++ usando `asm {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não use o Dev-C++, ele é bem problemático. Mas existem IDE para Aseembly sim, só para citar alguns tem o [WinAsm](http://www.winasm.net/), o [Fresh](https://fresh.flatassembler.net/), [EasyCode](http://easycode.cat/English/), [VisualMASM](http://www.visualmasm.com/) e tem ainda outros mais simples, editores que ajudam um pouco.